# MS Access Query to update

Tags: ms-access

Trying to update Packet.MSGState to P where if not R or D and it is Y in table Packet.MSGState

```
UPDATE Packet SET Packet.MSGState = 'P'
Where (MSGState <> 'R' and  MSGState <> 'D') and
Exists
(Select  MSGTO.Selected
From MSGTO
Where MSGTO.MSGTO = Packet.MSGTO and  MSGTO.Selected = 'Y')
```

Thanks Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
UPDATE Packet
INNER JOIN MSGTO ON Packet.MSGTO = MSGTO.MSGTO
SET Packet.MSGState = 'P'
where (Packet.MSGState is null    or
(Packet.MSGState<>'R' And Packet.MSGState<>'D') )
and  MSGTO.Selected = 'Y' ;
```

Comment: It looks as if null was the problem thanks to all that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use IN clause as following

```
UPDATE Packet SET Packet.MSGState = 'P'
Where (MSGState <> 'R' and  MSGState <> 'D') and
Packet.MSGTO IN
(Select  MSGTO.MSGTO
From MSGTO
Where  MSGTO.Selected = 'Y' and MSGTO.Selected IS NOT NULL )
```